# Excel VBA — How to combine text from 'n' cells in each row?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to edit a CSV file, but I'm having trouble merging columns. Apparently there's a myriad of different ways to merge cells together, but I haven't found anything that will fit what I'm looking to do. I've seen several options that show how to merge a cells in a row to another cell, or make many cells into a list, but what I need is so basic that I'm shocked I couldn't find a solution. I need to loop through all the rows in the worksheet and combine the text from columns B, C, and D into one cell. How can this be done quickly using VBA?

```
// 7 Columns (before subroutine)
-------------------------------------------
|  1  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
-------------------------------------------
|  6  |  L  |  M  |  N  |  2  |  8  |  5  |
-------------------------------------------
|  4  |  X  |  Y  |  Z  |  9  |  1  |  7  |
-------------------------------------------
// etc


// 5 Columns (after subroutine)
---------------------------------------
|  1  |  A - B - C  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
---------------------------------------
|  6  |  L - M - N  |  2  |  8  |  5  |
---------------------------------------
|  4  |  X - Y - Z  |  9  |  1  |  7  |
---------------------------------------
// etc
```

Comment: [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will merge the cells then delete the columns.

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lastrow, I as long

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 1 To lastrow
        ws.Cells(I, 2).Value = ws.Cells(I, 2).Value & " - " & ws.Cells(I, 3).Value & " - " & ws.Cells(I, 4).Value
    Next I
    ws.Range(ws.Columns(3), ws.Columns(4)).Delete
End Sub
```